# Deploying Databricks in a custom Vnet

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, vnet, databricks-connect

I have enabled secure cluster connectivity and trying to deploy Databricks in my custom Vnet.

I have created a Vnet - and configured two subnets. Now when I try to create a databricks workspace, MY VNET IS NOT SHOWING UP IN THE DROP DOWN.

How do I resolve this?

Vnet and Databricks are in the same region and in the same Resource group as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Vnet and Databricks are in the same region and in the same Resource group as well.

There are **multiple** reasons why your **Vnet** is not showing up in the dropdown when you are creating a `Databricks workspace` from portal, even though both the resources are located in same **region**. You may check the below steps.

1. Make sure that you have the required permissions in `Vnet` to add the same `Vnet` in `Databricks` workspace.
2. If you created the `VNet` before attempting to create the `Databricks workspace`, it might not immediately appear in the dropdown list. In this case, you should refresh the page and try creating the workspace again.
3. If you’re still encountering issues in the current region, consider creating the **VNet** and **Databricks** workspace in another **region**.

I am able to see the existing `VNet` if I follow the steps mentioned above for using an existing `VNet` while creating the `Databricks workspace`.

[image]